# Magento 2: Custom url for state=onsale produtcs

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

Right now I'm able to see all my on sale products here:

**http://wwww.domain.com/products?state=onsales**

(products is a category that lists all products)

I would like to change that url or create a new one with:
**http://wwww.domain.com/promotions**

What's the best way to achieve this?

Do I need to create a new module with custom url and then list all the products on sale?

Comment: You can use a url redirection its the easy way

Comment: Hi @MohamedElMrabet That's what I ended up doing for now. :)